# Maya add shelf separator: everything gives errors or doesn't work how as I expect it

Tags: python, maya, mel

Trying to create a shelf separator on Maya 2020 on Linux into any currently open shelf (which happens here to be named `Custom` but I want a thing that works on any shelf). I have tried a few things so far:

###### 1. When using `addShelfSeparator();` in the MEL commandline or as a shelf button in the shelf I want the separator:

```py
// Error: file: /s/apps/packages/cg/maya/2020.4.9-45.0/platform-linux/scripts/startup/shelf.mel line 594: Object's window not found.
```

###### 2. When using `separator -width 12 -height 35 -style "shelf" -hr false;` as in the `shelf.mel` at line 594 while the Attribute Editor is open:

```py
// Error: line 1: Object's window not found.
```

###### 3. Same as the above, but with the Attribute Editor closed:

It creates a separator in the Attribute Editor's lower half:

[image]

```py
// Result: AttributeEditor|MainAttributeEditorLayout|formLayout52|AEmenuBarLayout|separator91
```

###### 4. With the following code:

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

gShelfTopLevel = mel.eval("global string $gShelfTopLevel; $temp = $gShelfTopLevel;")
currentShelf = cmds.tabLayout(gShelfTopLevel, q=True, st=True)

cmds.separator(currentShelf, width=12, height=35, style="shelf", hr=False)
```

I get this error:

```py
global string $gShelfTopLevel; $temp = $gShelfTopLevel;
// Result: Shelf|MainShelfLayout|formLayout17|ShelfLayout // 
# Error: Object's window not found.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 7, in <module>
# RuntimeError: Object's window not found. #
```

Why `addShelfSeparator();` isn't working in the first place? It's supposed to be the "official" tool to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close with your code! It doesn't seem like there's [any documentation](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2024/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/separator.html) on what `separator` takes as a positional argument, but you would just need to pass the shelf as the `parent` keyword argument of `separator` like so:

```py
cmds.separator(width=12, height=35, style="shelf", hr=False, parent=currentShelf)
```

Alternatively, you can set the [default UI parent](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2024/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/setParent.html) first, like so:

```py
cmds.setParent(currentShelf)
cmds.separator(width=12, height=35, style="shelf", hr=False)
```

If you query the parent, you might see that the Attribute Editor is the default parent, which is why the separator goes to that location.

```py
cmds.setParent(query=True)
# Result: 'AttributeEditor|MainAttributeEditorLayout|formLayout52|AEmenuBarLayout'
```

You can see in `shelf.mel` that the `loadShelf` proc runs `setParent` on the shelf name as well, which is probably why `addShelfSeparator` has no need to set it itself and acts the way it does.

```
 59 global proc loadShelf(int $index)
 60 {
    ...
 79                 setParent $shelfName;
```